# Taking Selected Item of ListBox into selected TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListBox object which allows multiple selection and also for the selected item's to be removed.

Now I have an additional problem, which relates to a ListBox and 3 TextBoxes.
I want it to work so that when I shift the focus into or mouseover any of the textboxes, I would like for the ListBox  selected items to be copied into the textbox which recieved the focus/mouseover.

How can I do that?
Please Help me.

Comment: You should make more of an effort  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (especially _"Sample code and data"_ and _"spelling, grammar and formatting"_)

Comment: @TimSchmelter you're not avoiding the ban of what have you tried comments are you?

Comment: @SamIam: Since when is "what have you tried" a bad question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131031/147438

Comment: @TimSchmelter since yesterday.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic/172760#172760

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, it's been banned since yesterday.  It's been a bad question for years

Comment: @SamIam: I assume you've confused me with Soner since he wanted to see code. However, imho it's not  bad to tell (new) users that they should show what they've tried. That clarifies the question and shows that somebody has tried anything at all before asking a question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you assumed wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can grab ONE option item from the listbox,
To get more than one you will have to loop through the collection of option items in the listbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function GrabFromListbox() {
      window.document.getElementById("TextArea1").value += window.document.getElementById("lstFruits").options[window.document.getElementById("lstFruits").selectedIndex].text + "\n";
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <select id="lstFruits" name="lstFruits" multiple="multiple" size="8">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select</option>
          <option value="1">Apples</option>
          <option value="2">Pears</option>
          <option value="3">Bananas</option>
          <option value="4">Oranges</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <input type="text" id="TextArea1" name="TextArea1" value="" onmouseover="GrabFromListbox()" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```